# How to programmatically remove packages and exclude directory during meteor deploy/bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

There are certain packages and directories I use only for development purposes within a project. Does meteor provide a way to remove them during meteor deploy or bundle?

Comment: You're looking for something like dev dependencies in npm packages?

Comment: I don't think so, at least not exactly. A simple scenario would be removing `autopublish` and `insecure` for production. You can comment them out in the `packages` file. But I'm asking if it can be done automatically with meteor (along with excluding directories as well). Right now, I'm using a bash script to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You can make meteor ignore directories by placing a `.` in front of them. Meteor will completely ignore them, including packages.

I'm not too sure you can do this of packages because you would have used it in your app somehow and it would be linked up. You can either have the package or you can't.

Alternatively you could make a bashscript that copies the required directories to a new directory for bundling/publishing

Comment: I only need to exclude them during deploy as they are still needed for development. Maybe this option isn't available with meteor right now. Not a biggie, just a bit of manual bash scripting will do.

Comment: With the current Meteor (0.8.1.1) there is no built-in way to exclude packages.  Its definitely something that would be useful and the core team knows.  We actually have two community devs meeting with the MDG folk today to talk more about this as part of the velocity test runner effort: https://github.com/xolvio/velocity   Goal for us is to avoid bundling test packages and assets.